# What are the differences between "to write" and "to be writing"?

Tags: continuous-aspect, be

> "I answered the phone in my apartment and heard the sloping drawl of one of my students, Travis. "Miss Diana," he said, "Could you come on down the stairs a minute?"
>
> It was early May on the Great Plains. The University of Nebraska had just let out for the summer, and there was an aroma of pasture and cow everywhere, even —when the wind was right — at the center of the city. I didn't want to be in Nebraska. I was 26 years old, and I wanted to be writing novels, not grading papers on detasseling corn."

These sentences have been transcribed from the following link:

https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/magazine/2004/07/11/the-goddess-of-flowers/f0ca69bf-fb03-47e2-bd6a-460073fbdf52/

If I write *I wanted to write novels* instead of *I wanted to be writing novels*, what differences will arise?

Comment: This is called the 'continuous infinitive'. There is a short explanation here http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive - and you may like to Google ***continuous infinitive*** for more information.  If none of these help then please edit your question to show the research you have done and say what you find difficult about the explanations.

Comment: I think this Q would fit better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but @chasly's link makes the relevant point that *continuous infinitive **refers to the same time** as that of the preceding verb*. In this case, the continuous form strengthens the connection to "being 26 years old" (with the implication that wanting to grade papers might be more appropriate at some *later* point in his career, but doesn't sit well with the creative ambitions of a younger man). But it's largely a stylistic choice - grammatically, the simple infinitive would be quite acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he "wants to write novels", he may also want to study, build houses, work hard but in different fields, go to the cinema, go on holidays and have a good time.

If he "wants to be writing", he is underlining his strong will and that he wants to continue doing it for a long time, as his main activity, his sole important activity.